# How do I add a CDATA to an already existing ElementString? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I have my XML file setup like this:

```
<Entry>
<Desired_due_date>date</Desired_due_date>
<Order_number>order</Order_number>
<Series_number>series</Series_number>
<Product_name>product</Product_name>
</Entry>
```

I want to add CDATA without dropping the tags f.e.:

```
<Product_name>[CDATA[Z19 7HW]]</Product_name>
```

Every solution I found either makes a new node which messes up my structure or drops the tags.

My code looks something like this:

```
writer.WriteComment("Results in XML format."); 
writer.WriteStartElement("Entries");
writer.WriteElementString("Series_number", entries[i].Series_number);
writer.WriteElementString("End_date_2", entries[i].End_date2);
writer.WriteElementString("Norm", entries[i].Norm);
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: As written, the code above makes a root level <Entries> element, then proceeds to directly write values for an individual element. This differs from the above XML structure, which uses an <Entry> element. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `XmlWriter.WriteElementString`. Instead:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("elementname");
writer.WriteCData("text that goes in CDATA section");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I've tried this solution before but it adds another level to my element which I do not want.

Comment: By "level", do you mean that the code in this answer adds an unwanted child element to your output XML?